# Getting index error in a Python `for` loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, tuples, indexoutofboundsexception

The goal: Turn an empty ASCII grid into a tic-tac-toe board.
It should look this this when empty:

```
        |        |     
        |        |    
    ____|________|____
        |        |    
        |        |    
    ____|________|____
        |        |    
        |        |    
        |        |
```

The error:

```
def myformat(moves, line):
# there's got to be a better way to do this
    if line in [1, 4, 7]:
        if moves[line] == 'x':
            return "\  /"
        elif moves[line] == 'o':
            return " oo "
        elif moves[line] == 'none':
            return "    "
    elif line in [2, 5, 8]:
        if moves[line] == x:
            return " xx "
        elif moves[line] == o:
            return "o  o"
        elif moves[line] == "none":
            return "    "
    elif line in [3, 6]:
        if moves[line] == x:
            return "/__\b"
        elif moves[line] == o:
            return "o__o"
        elif moves[line] == "none":
            return "____"
    elif line == 9:
        if moves[line] == x:
            return "/__\b"
        elif moves[line] == o:
            return "o__o"
        elif moves[line] == "none":
            return "    "        
    else:
        print("Fatal error.")
>>> moves = ['none']*9
>>> moves
['none', 'none', 'none', 'none', 'none', 'none', 'none', 'none', 'none']
>>> for line in range(1, 10):
   print("{}|{}|{}".format((myformat(moves, line))))

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#24>", line 2, in <module>
    print("{}|{}|{}".format((myformat(moves, line))))
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

[full code](https://github.com/jyn514/python-challenges/blob/master/tic_tac_two.py) since people got mad last time I only posted part

I don't understand why it's mentioning tuples. The only one I see is the range(1, 10) function, and since it's a for loop there shouldn't be an index error. All comments and criticism are appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `myformat` should return a 3-len tuple to feed `format`, but it only returns a string. what do you expect format can guess to fill the other fields? maybe try `print("{0}|{0}|{0}"`

Comment: Python, like most programing languages, counts indexes from "0", not from "1"  - your last index in "moves" is "8", not "9".

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre You're quite correct. I wrote `return` on each variable when I meant to put something like `a='. . . ', b = ' . . . ', c=' . . . ' return a,b,c.` I'll change it and see if it fixes the problem.

Comment: glad to be of help.

Answer (score 0):

In your example with line = 1 myformat() would return a string of 5 whitespaces..

let's try that

```
>>> ret_val = '     '
>>> '{} | {} | {}'.format(ret_val)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

@Jean-François Fabre, already explained that format expects 3 values.
Since there is only 1 value string format can't find the missing values.
You need to tell format what it should place where by providong indices.

```
>>> ret_val = '     '
>>> '{0} | {0} | {0}'.format(ret_val)
'      |       |      '
```

Answer (score 0):

There are three issues with your code.

The first is that your calling code expects to get three values, but you're only returning one value from your function.

The second issue is that within the function you're indexing `moves` with values that come from `range(1, 10)` in the calling code. Since the `stop` argument to `range` is excluded, the largest value is `9`. That's out of bounds in `moves` (which has nine values). Python indexes from zero, so you probably want `range(0, 9)` or just `range(9)` (or you need to subtract one from the value before taking each index).

The third issue is that you seem to be using `line` for two different purposes in your function. You're using it to index the array of squares on the board (via the `moves` list). And you're also using it to number the horizontal rows of text in your output. Those aren't the same thing, and so you're going to get odd results if you keep using them interchangeably.

I'm not exactly sure what the best way to compute the values you want is. If you stick to iterating over the rows of the output and want your function to return three values (for the three squares the row crosses), you'd need to pass in a `line` value from `range(9)` and then index with `line // 3` plus a value from `range(3)` (which will direct you to the three different squares).